# CSS Flex basis grandchild

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm having a hard time trying to get this to work.

```css
div {
  min-height: 100px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px;
}

.sub-container {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
}

.child, .grand-child {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow; 
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="desired-result container yellow">

  <div class="child red">
  1
  </div>
  
  <div class="child red">
  2
  </div>

</div>

<div class="issue container yellow">

  <div class="sub-container green">
    <div class="grand-child red">
    3
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="sub-container green">
    <div class="grand-child red">
    4
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hugojg/dvasufot/21/

I want to make the elements width respect `flex-basis` while being a `grand-child` from my container (`display: flex`).

How can I change the code to get 3 and 4 to be like 1 and 2?

Just for reference, I'm having this problem because of bootstrap 4.
I have an element between `.row` and the `.col-sm-6(*)` element which is the exact same scenario described above.

EDIT:

```
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

That would be a realistic scenario.
Taken from the Bootstrap 4 docs and added a wrapper element around the inputs.
Everything I want is that this wrapper do not change the elements positioning.

Comment: But your `grand-child` don't know of `container`, it only know of `sub-container`, so how to you mean it should relate to `container`? .. if to fill 50% of it, you got an answer already.

Comment: Ignore the sub-container width of 50%, I was just shooting in the dark.
Isn't there a way to make the grand-child fills 50% of .container width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I get this, but you want 3 & 4 be exactly like 1 & 2? If so, here you are:

```css
div {
  min-height: 100px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px;
}

.sub-container {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
}

.child, .grand-child {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow; 
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="desired-result container yellow">

  <div class="child red">
  1
  </div>
  
  <div class="child red">
  2
  </div>

</div>

<div class="issue container yellow">

  <div class="sub-container green">
    <div class="grand-child red">
    3
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="sub-container green">
    <div class="grand-child red">
    4
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

You have to change `flex-basis` parameter, `50%` for `child` and `100%` for `grandchild`, as they are subs of them.

Comment: I can't really change flex-basis value as they are generated by bootstrap classes.

Comment: @hugo00 This answer provide a solution to your question. If you can't translate its answer to your own code, post one that show the real issue, not pseudo code.

Comment: I edited the question and added the real scenario below. Sorry about that.

Comment: @hugo00 I edited my answer. Look if it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> Everything I want is that this wrapper do not change the elements
>   positioning.

When you add a `.wrapper` around the `col-*` elements, you break Bootstraps structure, where `row`/`col-*` has a parent/child relation ship, which btw also Flexbox has.

That means, you can't tell a flex parent's grand child to pick up from its width.

If you instead add the `.wrapper` around your `label`/`input`, the layout will be the same as w/o the `.wrapper`

Stack snippet

```css
.wrapper {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

If you want to add your `.wrapper` around the `col-*` elements, and keep Bootstrap's structure, you need to add/update its classes to something like below sample.

*Note, when double up those classes, also their extra padding is added, and if that is unwanted, they need to reset.*

```css
.wrapper {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="wrapper row col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper row col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I went with a similar solution from your second snippet.
Even tough @PStarczewski answered my original question correctly, this is what I really wanted.
I'm sorry about not being clear about this at first.

Comment: @hugo00 May I suggest you upvote my answer and accept _PStarczewski_, as it actually answered the initial question. That would more appropriate if you ask me :)

Comment: makes sense to me